# How to limit/retrieve inner fields of a MongoDB document when using $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have documents in a collection called `notification`that looks as below.

```javascript
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56438985e68a78f46b1fd9cc"),
"modulename" : "Admin Control Panel",
"modulecode" : "acp",
"eventnames" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "New user account added",
        "code" : 100,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5655fb5d710557d8f7895d94"),
        "emails" : [ 
            "email1@abc.com"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "User permissions changes",
        "code" : 200,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5655fb5d710557d8f7895d93"),
        "emails" : [ 
            "email1@abc.com", 
            "email2@abc.com", 
            "email3@abc.com"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I want to retrieve only the `emails` property of an object from `eventnames` array with a matching of `code` 100.

I tried `$elemMatch` to filter the document and got a result as below.

Query:

```javascript
db.getCollection('notifications').find({modulecode: 'acp'},{eventnames: { $elemMatch: {code:100}}})
```

Results:

```javascript
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56438985e68a78f46b1fd9cc"),
"eventnames" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "New user account added",
        "code" : 100,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5655fb5d710557d8f7895d94"),
        "emails" : [ 
            "email1@abc.com"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I am close to what I want but would like get only the `emails` as below

```javascript
"emails" : [ 
            "email1@abc.com"
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by specifying additional terms in your projection to include just the `emails` field of the `eventnames` array and omit `_id`:

```js
db.getCollection('notifications').find({modulecode: 'acp'}, {
    eventnames: { $elemMatch: {code:100}}, 
    'eventnames.emails': 1,
    _id: 0
})
```

Results:

```js
{
    "eventnames" : [ 
        {
            "emails" : [ 
                "email1@abc.com"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that you still have the parent `eventnames` field, but that's required as you can't change the overall shape of the documents with `find`. If you really wanted to get rid of that for some reason you would need to use `aggregate`.

Comment: Thanks..I think I don't need to use ` aggregate` unless there is any performance benefits to use it.